# jQuery on() and remove parent not working

Tags: jquery

We have following code

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.details').on('click','.remove', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'remove',
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
</head>
<html>
 <div class="details">
    <table>
     <thead>
      ...
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><button class="remove" value="somevalue1">clickme!</button></td>
       <td><button class="remove" value="somevalue2">clickme!</button></td>
       <td><button class="remove" value="somevalue3">clickme!</button></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </details>
</html>
```

Unfortunately doesn't work, how to remove  where is the button? (of course function works for example: alert())

UPDATE: Check now...

Comment: your html is invalid.tbody should have tr and td inside it.

Comment: there is no TR in your html

Comment: I also don't see a `.details` element in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different issues in your code.

1, Your html is invalid. You need to wrap your button inside `tr` and `td`

2, There is no element with class `.details`. If there is such element, it should be the parent of table. Then only the event delegation will work.

3, You can use `.closest()` instead of callong `parent()` twice

Your html should look like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="remove" value="somevalue1">clickme!</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="remove" value="somevalue2">clickme!</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="remove" value="somevalue3">clickme!</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And jquery will be

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

});
```

In the above example I delegated the click event with `document` .You can replace it with any othe parent element which is present on dom ready.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/384/)

In your editerd code, `$(this)` refers to ajax, not the clicked element. So you need to save it temporarily inorder to refer it in success handler.

```
$('.details').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    var obj = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'storageorder-inventory-remove',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function() {

            $(obj).closest("tr").remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh man, hate me. I just copy/paste (some data in html was generated by functions, like buttons). Anyway i updated my code, check it now. Sorry for compliations

Comment: Yea, thanks very well. Give me a minus for my stupidity. Thanks